# How do I write ints out to a text file with the low bits on the right side (Bigendian)

Tags: c#, endianness

By default the BinaryWriter class writes int values with the low bits on the left (e.g. (int)6 becomes 06 00 00 00 when the resulting file is viewed in a hex editor). I need the low bits on the right (e.g. 00 00 00 06).

How do I achieve this?

EDIT: Thanks strager for giving me the name for what I was looking for. I've edited the title and tags to make it easier to find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jon Skeet has an EndianBitConverter [here](http://www.pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil/) that should do the job. Just use big/little endian as desired. Alternatively, just shift the data a few times ;-p

```
        int i = 6;
        byte[] raw = new byte[4] {
            (byte)(i >> 24), (byte)(i >> 16),
            (byte)(i >> 8), (byte)(i)};
```

Answer (score 6):

Not really a built in way but you can use this:  [EndianBit*](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/). Thanks to Jon Skeet :P

Comment: Within seconds of eachother; sorry. You've my +1, though ;-p

Answer (score 2):

You are looking to change the [Byte Order (aka Endianness)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order).  You want to print out **big endian**.  Not sure how you'd do that in C#, but you can swap your bytes in the integer before sending it to the BinaryWritter class.

You can check the endianness of the current system using [System.BitConverter.IsLittleEndian](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian.aspx).  I am not sure if BinaryWriter uses the system's endianness or little endian for compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

If you're determined to use something built in, there are a number of overloads of  System.Net.IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder().

These will do what you want because it's overwhelmingly likely that 'host' order is always little-endian, and 'network' order is big-endian, which is what you want.

Bit of a hack to use these though, if you're not doing anything at all to do with networking.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the BitConverter to get a byte array, then reverse it. Something like:

```
Byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(number);
Array.Reverse(bytes);

// Then, to write the values you use
writer.Write(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't help now, but I created a [connect ticket](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=484149) for BinaryReder/Writer to support Bigendian out the box. Go vote for it [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=484149).